# Ag-Grid Prevent API.StopEditing() callback when editing next cell (Angular)

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I'm currently working on AG Grid for angular 5. I have an issue with cell editing function. With my click event, I'm enabling editing mode of selected rows column programmatically using the following code

```
selectedNods.forEach(element => {
    if (element.node.selected)
        element.node.gridApi.startEditingCell({
            rowIndex: element.node.rowIndex,
            colKey: "account"
        });
});
```

This works fine. But when I enter into a cell for the purpose of editing, 
all other cells back to normal mode from editing mode.
I want to keep all selected rows specified cells should be editable, even when I'm editing a cell. 
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full row editing mode will help you instead of `cell editing`.
Use `[editType]="'fullRow'"` property of [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid).

Once you do this, you can use `cellClicked` event to make the row/cell editable.

```
(cellClicked)="onCellClicked($event)"
```

While in your component,

```
onCellClicked($event){
  // check whether the current row is already opened in edit or not
  if(this.editingRowIndex != $event.rowIndex) {
    console.log($event);
    $event.api.startEditingCell({
      rowIndex: $event.rowIndex,
      colKey: $event.column.colId
    });
    this.editingRowIndex = $event.rowIndex;
  }
}
```

Check this live example in **[Plunk - row editing ag-grid](https://plnkr.co/edit/1NZVLBgVLlRMrJaaRtOb?p=preview)**

Comment: Yes. It helps. Thank you Paritosh.